# Monitor and run .bat file once

Tags: powershell

I am running the powershell script attached. I want to monitor a folder for PDF's (Multiple) and run a .bat file. This is just an example. For some reason the .bat file runs as many times as I have PDF's in folder. So if I put three files at once in the folder, the .bat file runs three times. Is there anyway to make the .bat file only run once even if there are multiple files.

```
$folder = 'C:\Transfers'
$filter = '*.PDF'   
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property 
@{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, 
LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Start-Sleep -s 5
Start-Process 'C:\Transfers\Movebat.bat'}
```

Comment: How is the created delegate supposed to know that there are more files coming?  It can't.  A trigger is a trigger.  Perhaps instead of having the Movebat.bat process all of the files in the directory, have the event pass the file to it and go with it getting called one time for each.  That's my opinion.